# Spring Boot GUI Testing Selenium WebDriver

Tags: angularjs, spring, selenium, spring-boot, gui-testing

I developped a Spring Boot / Angular JS app. Now I'm trying to implement some GUI interface tests.

I tryed to use the Selenium ChromeDriver, so I added the Selenium dependency :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

And I created my first test :

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = MyMainClass.class)
public class SeleniumTest {
    private WebDriver driver;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "my/path/to/chomedriver");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
    }

    @Test
    public void testTest() throws Exception {
        driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
    }
}
```

This works fine. But now I want to get my app pages with :

```
driver.get("http://localhost:8080/");
```

But I get an "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED" in the chrome browser.

I think it's because I need to set up my test to run my web app before to run the test but I don't find how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your case service is not started. Try something like this this.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class SeleniumTest {
    @LocalServerPort
    private int port;
    private WebDriver driver;

    @Value("${server.contextPath}")
    private String contextPath;
    private String base;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "my/path/to/chromedriver");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        this.base = "http://localhost:" + port;
    }

    @Test
    public void testTest() throws Exception {
        driver.get(base + contextPath);
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

Add the dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Springboot doesn't seems to recognize the @SpringBootTest annotation

Comment: Before your answer I tried to add @IntegrationTest and it seems to works, but probably it's not the right way to do !?

Comment: The main problem is to let test run your spring boot application. I posted my way but there are some more.

Comment: You can use the Spring Boot Maven plugin to start up the container before your selenium tests run in Maven,

Comment: @StanislavL Your answer wasn't working because my project was under an old Spring Boot version (1.2.6) I updated it to 1.5.3 and it works. Thanks !

Comment: I wrote an article with the latest versions of selenium and spring boot and you can find all details here: https://www.swtestacademy.com/selenium-spring-boot-cucumber-junit5-project/