# How to configure Selenium WebDriver with Spring Boot for UI testing?

Tags: java, spring, selenium, spring-boot, selenium-webdriver

Not able to configure `WebDriver` correctly hence my functional test are failing for `UI`.

I looked into both these SO links but not sure how to use the `geckodriver.exe` here and what is purpose of it.

- [Spring Boot GUI Testing Selenium WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44072400/spring-boot-gui-testing-selenium-webdriver)
- [Spring Boot Web Application using Selenium WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44781339/spring-boot-web-application-using-selenium-webdriver)

I also looked for some online tutorials where `Selenium` is configured with `Spring Boot` but most of them are with older versions of Spring.

**UPDATE:**

- Downloaded and stored `IEDriverServer.exe` in `C:\FAST` directory.
- Added maven dependency for IE
- Modified code base by adding `System.getProperty` and pointing it to the location of `IEDriverServer.exe`

Any guidance will be helpful.

**pom.xml**

```
   <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-ie-driver</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

**src/main/java/Application.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public WebDriver webDriver() {
        return new InternetExplorerDriver();
    }

}
```

**src/test/java/ApplicationTests.java**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class ApplicationTests {

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
    }

}
```

**GoogleSearchPageSeleniumTests.java**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class GoogleSearchPageSeleniumTests {

    @Autowired
    private WebDriver webDriver;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:\\FAST\\IEDriverServer.exe");
        webDriver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
    }

    @Test
    public void getSearchPage() {
        this.webDriver.get("https://www.google.com");
        WebElement element = this.webDriver.findElement(By.name("q"));
        assertNotNull(element);
    }

}
```

**Error:**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'com.jpmchase.gct.ft.GoogleSearchPageSeleniumTests': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'webDriver'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'webDriver' defined in com.jpmchase.gct.ft.Application: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver]: Factory method 'webDriver' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.ie.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver. The latest version can be downloaded from http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:584)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:370)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1336)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:393)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:118)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:44)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:246)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'webDriver' defined in com.jpmchase.gct.ft.Application: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver]: Factory method 'webDriver' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.ie.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver. The latest version can be downloaded from http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:591)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1246)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1096)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:535)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$1(AbstractBeanFactory.java:353)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverScope.get(WebDriverScope.java:58)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:350)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1135)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1062)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:581)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver]: Factory method 'webDriver' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.ie.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver. The latest version can be downloaded from http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:583)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.ie.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver. The latest version can be downloaded from http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:847)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:124)
    at org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriverService.access$000(InternetExplorerDriverService.java:32)
    at org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(InternetExplorerDriverService.java:167)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:339)
    at org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.setupService(InternetExplorerDriver.java:291)
    at org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.<init>(InternetExplorerDriver.java:213)
    at org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.<init>(InternetExplorerDriver.java:152)
    at com.jpmchase.gct.ft.Application.webDriver(Application.java:20)
    at com.jpmchase.gct.ft.Application$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$fe85b267.CGLIB$webDriver$0(<generated>)
    at com.jpmchase.gct.ft.Application$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$fe85b267$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$88167d66.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:365)
    at com.jpmchase.gct.ft.Application$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$fe85b267.webDriver(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
    ... 41 more

2019-02-08 14:38:56.650  INFO 12096 --- [       Thread-2] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@3c77d488: startup date [Fri Feb 08 14:38:56 EST 2019]; root of context hierarchy

Process finished with exit code -1
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally this is what I tried and it worked.

**pom.xml**

```
 <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
      <!--  <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>-->
    </dependencies>
```

**src/test/resources (manual download of exe required)**

```
chromedriver.exe
```

**BaseSeleniumTests.java**

```
public abstract class BaseSeleniumTests {

    private static final String CHROMEDRIVER_EXE = "chromedriver.exe";
    protected WebDriver driver;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        String driverFile = findFile();
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
        ChromeDriverService service = new ChromeDriverService.Builder()
                .usingDriverExecutable(new File(driverFile))
                .build();
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("--no-sandbox"); // Bypass OS security model, MUST BE THE VERY FIRST OPTION
        options.addArguments("--headless");
        options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
        options.addArguments("start-maximized"); // open Browser in maximized mode
        options.addArguments("disable-infobars"); // disabling infobars
        options.addArguments("--disable-extensions"); // disabling extensions
        options.addArguments("--disable-gpu"); // applicable to windows os only
        options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage"); // overcome limited resource problems
        options.merge(capabilities);
        this.driver = new ChromeDriver(service, options);
    }

    private String findFile() {
        ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
        URL url = classLoader.getResource(CHROMEDRIVER_EXE);
        return url.getFile();
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        if (driver != null) {
            driver.quit();
        }
    }
```

**GoogleSearchPageTraditionalSeleniumTests.java**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class GoogleSearchPageTraditionalSeleniumTests extends BaseSeleniumTests {

    @Test
    public void getSearchPage() {
        this.driver.get("https://www.google.com");
        WebElement element = this.driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
        assertNotNull(element);
    }

}
```

Comment: I had to add `@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)` in the class so i could make the tests work

Comment: I wrote an article with the latest versions and you can check all details here: https://www.swtestacademy.com/selenium-spring-boot-cucumber-junit5-project/

Answer (score 3):

Please see my answer here [Use Webdriver Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50566186/can-we-add-drivers-in-selenium-as-maven-depandancies/50587347#50587347) on how to invoke browser without the need to download the binary files (You will need to add a dependecy to your maven) then the rest is simple , so your code will looks like this:

```
    @Test
    public void getSearchPage() {
    WebDriverManager.firefoxdriver().setup();
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.webDriver.get("https://www.google.com");
    WebElement element = driver.webDriver.findElement(By.name("q"));
    assertNotNull(element);
}
```

Comment: Tried your solution and looks like it is working because I have gone past that error and now some other error. This error could be because of a corporate firewall. `io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManagerException: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com:443`

Comment: Yeah , its looks like maven can't get the dependencies. You can then use the old route by downloading the binary files and then pass the path to run the browser

Answer (score 1):

You will need to

- add a Maven dependency to the `selenium-ie-driver`
- Download the [Internet Explorer Webdriver](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver)
- Set the system property `webdriver.ie.driver` to the path of the executable

Selenium starts this as a background process and communicates via network connection. The webdriver takes control of the Internet Explorer.

Comment: @Dens - Used your feedback and modified my code (see above) but still same error.